# Obtaining information from a list/dict in Python

Tags: python, json, list, api, dictionary

I understand this question may have been asked in many different formats in the past. I also checked the recommended answers when I wrote the question title, and I haven't found what I need.

I'm new to Python so my understanding of lists and dictionaries is slowly growing. I'm struggling at the moment with what I can only describe as a nested dictionary, but I don't think that's the right way to refer to it.

Using requests.get(...).json() I obtain a list of a json-like object, like this:

> [{'key': {'key': 'projkey1'}, 'name': 'projname1'}, {'key': {'key':
> 'projkey2'}, 'name': 'projname2'}, {'key': {'key': 'projkey3'},
> 'name': 'projname3'}]

Let's assume that's stored in 'ppl'. I now use the following code:

```
for entries in ppl:
    print(entries)
```

And that returns the following:

> {'key': {'key': 'projkey1'}, 'name': 'projname1'}
>
> {'key': {'key': 'projkey2'}, 'name': 'projname2'}
>
> {'key': {'key': 'projkey3'}, 'name': 'projname3'}

Next, if I want to get the name element, I can simply ask for:

```
print(entries.get('name'))
```

And that'll return just the entry of projname1, projname2, etc.

Here's my problem. If I ask for print(entries.get('key')), I actually get back:

> **{'key':** 'projkey1'**}**

It's obvious why - it's because "key" is also nested under "key", but I don't know how to get just the item under that nested "key".

**EDIT: I have the answer, but now, why is my data being returned with each character on a new line?**

Using this code:

```
for entries in ppl:
    print(entries.get('key')['key'])
    for keys in entries.get('key')['key']:
        print(keys)
```

The first print statement returns:

> projkey1

The second returns:

- p
- r
- o
- j
- k
- e
- y
- 1

Why is my data being output as individual characters?

Comment: `entries.get('key').get('key')` or simply `entries['key']['key']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for the edit:

You are looping through each character individually, and then printing each one. This means they are printed on different lines.

You should instead add each character to a string and print that:

```
for entries in ppl:

    result = ""

    print(entries.get('key')['key'])

    for char in entries.get('key')['key']:
        result += char

    print(result)
```

I changed the name of the iteration variable from `keys` to `char` because it accesses one character at a time rather than all the keys.

Comment: Perfect. I am now able to query an API to obtain project keys and then utilise the full key string to further query the API in another loop. Your help has come after a four day struggle, thankyou so much.

Comment: No worries :)  
If you have any more problems just leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use `entries["key"]["key"]`

This will first access `{'key':'projkey1'}`, and then get just `'projkey1'`.

Comment: Thankyou - I literally figured that out a short while after posting this question and you are of course exactly right. I do have a new problem though. I will edit my post to add the newer issue which is the fact that the data is being returned as individual characters on a line by line basis, rather than a whole word.

Comment: @Dan I'll be happy to help :)